# Add class for all parents element on native JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If I have some ".blocks"

```
body
    section
        .main-container
            .container
                .block
                .blcok
```

And I need add className for all parents block, div, section, body.

When I use jquwry I wrote like this:

```
    $(".block").parents().addClass('block-wrapp');
```

But now I must use native js.

```
window.onload = function() {

    let block = document.getElementsByClassName('block');

    for( let i = 0; i < block.length; i++ ) {
        block[i].parentNode.classList.add('block-wrapp');
    }
};
```

I try use

```
        let mainBlock = block[i].parentNode.className;
        console.log(mainBlock.parentNode);
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: `mainBlock` it's a classname of the `parentNode` .but you are console it `console.log(mainBlock.parentNode);` its wrong .change with `console.log(mainBlock)`

Comment: Do you want to add the same class on ALL parents? `body`, `section`, `.main-container` and `.container` ?

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all parents with a `while` statement:

```
// loop through selected elements
for( let i = 0; i < block.length; i++ ) {

    // get current looped element
    let node = block[i];

    // do this as long as we have a parent to go to 
    while (let parent = node.parentNode) {

        // add class on parent
        parent.classList.add('block-wrapp');

        // move up the tree
        node = parent;
    }
}
```

You can improve a bit the performance so you don't visit the same parents and traverse the entire tree over and over again for sibling elements. For this, get a list of processed parents and skip them the next time you encounter them:

```
let visitedParents = [];
while (parent = node.parentNode && visitedParents.indexOf(parent) === -1) {
    // ...

    // mark this parent as visited
    visitedParents.push(parent);
}
```

Finally, you should also stop when reaching the `body` element, otherwise you'll reach `html` and the `document`, which I presume you don't want to:

```
while (node.parentNode !== document.body && .... ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your parentNode to parentElement inside the loop